# CSS Triangle Appearing and Shouldn't Be: Why Is this?

Tags: css

[image]

Wifi Name 1, Wifi Name 2, and Wifi Name 3 all share the same class called `wifiarea`. The css for `wifiarea` is simply:

```
.wifiarea {
    height: 115px;
    width: 561px;
}
```

Each button has a default state and active state. For example the button to the right of 'Wifi Name 1 Text' is:

```
.wifibutton1>button{
    background:url(../toggle_off.png);
    border:0;
    width:191px;
    height:76px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.wifibutton1>button.wifibutton1active{
    background:url(../toggle_on.png);
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="fullairwifimenu" id="fullairwifimenu">

    <div class="wifiarea">
        <div class="wifitext">
        Wifi Name 1
        </div>
        <div class="wifibutton1">
            <button id="wifibutton1">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wifiarea">
        <div class="wifitext">
        Wifi Name 2
        </div>
        <div class="wifibutton2">
            <button id="wifibutton2">
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="wifiarea">
        <div class="wifitext">
        Wifi Name 3
        </div>
        <div class="wifibutton3">
            <button id="wifibutton3">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image that takes care of the background is popup_wifi2.png, see here:

[image]

After doing some research it seems like the border is the root of the issue.

**The goal/question: how do I get rid of that pesky little grey triangle? None of the associated images called in the css have it.**

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: HTML will helps... This isn't enough info

Comment: can you show your code or may be i think it is the issue of margin of padding.

Comment: Sorry Fiskolin, I added the HTML.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue on the quoted CSS/HTML block. Notice the base of the same triangle artifact at the top of the image?

Comment: How does your button become 'active'. Any JavaScript?

Comment: @OnoSendai great observation. See my updated question I added the png that is used as the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure your background is repeating:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat
```